# Time problem causes IMAP server to fail

Tags: time, ntp, imap

I've had a problem with my system time, when I execute the following:
    `date && touch test && stat test`

I get this result:
    
`Sun Jan 22 17:52:07 MSK 2012`
`File: test`
`Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file`
`Device: 1dh/29d Inode: 5543372     Links: 1`
`Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)`
`Access: 2012-01-22 17:19:39.000000000 +0400`
`Modify: 2012-01-22 17:19:39.000000000 +0400`
`Change: 2012-01-22 17:19:39.000000000 +0400`


 This causes my imap server to give me an error upon login, namely
`* BYE Clock skew detected. Check the clock on the file server`
I tried to solve this using ntpdate and ntpd daemon, but though neither give me an error, the situation does not change. I tried ubuntu forums but nobody seems to know what to do.
I would appreciate any help I could get.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one explanation why the time reported by `date` and the timestamp on a touched file would differ: the file you are touching is located on and NFS server and the server's time doesn't match the client's.

Check the time on the NFS server.